# Use the ratio test to determine if the infinite series $\sum_1^∞ {n^4\over 4^n}$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Use the ratio test to determine if the infinite series $\sum_1^∞ {n^4\over 4^n}$  converges or diverges

Comment: Are you sure that's the question, and not $\sum_{1}^\infty \frac{n^4}{4^n}$? Because $\frac{n^4}{4n}=\frac{1}4n^3\geq\frac{1}{4}$, so it obviously does not converge.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LaTeX but I tried using the ratio test to sub (n+1) for (n) in the original equation, and then simplify but I got stuck. I have $\displaystyle \frac{(n+1)^4}{4n^4}$

Answer (score 2):

Simplify and divide by the highest power term ($n^4$ in this case) $$\frac{(n+1)^4}{4n^4}=\frac{n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1}{4n^4}=\frac{1+4n^{-1}+6n^{-2}+4n^{-3}+n^{-4}}{4}$$Taking the limit as this value tends to infinity gives $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1+4n^{-1}+6n^{-2}+4n^{-3}+n^{-4}}{4}=\frac{1}{4}<1$$
Therefore, the series converges.

Comment: Our professor told us that the ratio test was to take 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=L$
Like I said I hope that's the right formatting for LaTeX, this is the first time I have used it.
So I used $\displaystyle \frac{n^4}{4^n}$ and tried to use that ratio test? Did I do it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy.

$\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\dfrac 14 \times \dfrac{(n+1)^4}{n^4}=\dfrac 14 \times \left(1+\dfrac 1n\right)^4$

$\exists N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N_0$, $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}<\dfrac 12$

EDIT: $N_0>\dfrac{1}{2^{\frac 14}-1}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^4}{4^n}\leq 24\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{n+3}{4}=\left.24\,\frac{x}{(1-x)^5}\right|_{x=\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{2048}{81}$$
and by decomposing $n^4$ as a linear combination of binomial coefficients you may also prove that the LHS equals $\displaystyle\color{red}{\frac{380}{81}}$, indeed.